# Reading docx file by using Apache POI if the docx file contains image, paragraph, table

Tags: apache-poi

How to read docx file in the same order if the document contains image, paragraph and then table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How far did you get? What problems did you encounter? How are you trying to "read" it - to html? something else? etc

Answer (score 2):

Reading and manipulating `.docx` files is possible with **Apache POI** Framework.
You'll need `XWPF` libraries and `ooxml-schemas` to be able to do this.
Here's an example how to read a Microsoft Word file:

```
public void readDocxFile() throws IOException
{
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.docx");
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);

    //Paragraphs
    List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = paragraphs.get(1);
    //Runs
    List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
    XWPFRun run = runs.get(1);
    run.setText("Some text");
    run.setFontSize(12);
    run.setBold(true);
    //etc.

    //Tables
    List<XWPFTable> tables = doc.getTables();
    XWPFTable table = tables.get(1);
    //Rows
    List<XWPFTableRow> rows = table.getRows();
    XWPFTableRow row = rows.get(1);
    //Cells
    List<XWPFTableCell> cells = row.getTableCells();
    XWPFTableCell cell = cells.get(1);
    cell.setText("Some text");
    cell.setParagraph(paragraph);
    //etc.
}
```

You can also create your own paragraphs, runs, tables etc. Here's a good tutorial for first steps with XWPF: [Apache POI - XWPF Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide.htm)

For the picture, try read the byte array with `.getData()`, or according to the [Apache POI Documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFPictureData.html) you can work with InputStream like `getPackagePart().getInputStream()`

After that, convert your byte array to an image - this [tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-image-to-byte-array-convert-byte-array-to-image/) seems heplful:

Comment: Hi funk,I am able to read paragraphs,tables but when there is a picture as part of document i tried to read that with document.getAllPictures(),the picture is coming in the output .docx document as cross symbol.Also when i try to open the output .docx document after reading the picture it displays message saying document contains unreadable data.please help me to solve this issue